# How to set authentication in Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, warden

I need simple authentication for blog. For a single person. Just login to the website

Can't configure sinatra_warden. Write the line

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'pry-byebug'
require "sinatra/activerecord"
require "carrierwave"
require "carrierwave/orm/activerecord"
require 'sinatra_warden'
require 'warden'

register Sinatra::Warden

use Rack::Session::Pool
```

in **app.rb**, but I get an error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `register' for main:Object
```

the gem [sinatra_warden](https://github.com/jsmestad/sinatra_warden) has installed. as well written `require "warden"` & `require "sinatra_warden"`

sinatra_warden 0.3.2

warden 1.2.6

When I add the `authorize!` method in controller, I get an error

```
undefined method `authorize!'
```

Comment: Show please the full code where you add this line.

Comment: added to the body of the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you didn't use the `sinatra/base` you should add `sinatra/namespace`. Add to your `app.rb` this require `require "sinatra/namespace"`.

> [`Sinatra::Namespace`](http://www.sinatrarb.com/contrib/namespace.html#label-Classic+Application+Setup) is an extension that adds namespaces to an
>   application. This namespaces will allow you to share a path prefix for
>   the routes within the namespace, and define filters, conditions and
>   error handlers exclusively for them. Besides that, you can also
>   **register helpers** and extensions that will be used only within the
>   namespace.

Or change your application to the modular style:

```
require "sinatra/base"

class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
  register Sinatra::Warden

  # The rest of your modular application code goes here...
end
```

Comment: in the app.rb added `require "sinatra/base"` and `class Myapp < Sinatra::Base`. Application worked! But when I add the `authorize!` method in controller, I get an error `NoMethodError - undefined method authenticated? for nil:NilClass`

Comment: log `Sinatra::Base#options is deprecated and will be removed, use #settings instead.`

Comment: @Chumak this is an another question ). Post another question and maybe I can help.

Comment: only an hour :)